# What is the Python equivalent of map in Ruby and Javascript?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Say for example I want to split string `"12:30-14:40"` and have the result in a matrix like: `[["12","30"],["14","40"]]`.

I can do this in JavaScript with:

```
"12:30-14:40".split("-").map(function(x) {
    return x.split(':');
});
```

and in Ruby with:

```
 "12:30-14:40".split("-").map{|x| x.split(":")}
```

What would be the python equivalent for the above?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Python and using [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) you will have something like:

```
In [1]: map(lambda x: x.split(":"), "12:30-14:40".split("-"))
Out[1]: [['12', '30'], ['14', '40']]
```

Comment: This is the closest way, but (since map needs a lambda) I think that a list comprehension would be faster and more Pythonic.

Comment: this one is slower than list comprehension based solution.

Comment: Indeed, I just wrote the closest translation I could remember. However I wouldn't recommend to do it this way. Instead I'd use a list comprehension.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary & everybody: Yes is slower but is the equivalent of the above code in JS and Ruby,and I am trying more to learn language possibilities, especially things I may overlook or don't get from documentation.

Answer (score 13):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
>>> [i.split(':') for i in "12:30-14:40".split('-')]
[['12', '30'], ['14', '40']]
```

Comment: So there is no way without for/in like in JS and Ruby?

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu map is not a method of list in python it is built in function http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map

Comment: @dm03514 That I already saw when I did `"12:30-14:40".split("-").map`, and got `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'map'`. What I had in mind was something like if there is  the andrefsp answer without the `for/in`.

Answer (score 2):

From [Ruby and Python by example](http://grschafer.com/guides/2013/08/20/ruby-and-python-by-example/)

> #### Ruby
>
> ```
> a = [1,2,3]
> a.map { |x| x**2 } # [1,4,9]
> # map returns a new array
> # use map! to mutate the original
>
> a.collect { |x| x**2 } # [1,4,9]
> # collect is an alias of map
> ```
>
> #### Python
>
> ```
> a = [1,2,3]
> [x**2 for x in a] # [1,4,9]
> map(lambda x: x**2, a) # [1,4,9]
> ```

If you'd like python to return a list, just like ruby, instead: `list(map(lambda x: x**2, a))`